# Where is the difference between iterating over a dictionary with list(dict.items()) and dict.items() in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I wonder why there are these two ways to iterate over a dictionary

```
states = {
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI'
}

for key, item in states.items():
    print(key, item)

for key, item in list(states.items()):
    print(key, item
```

As far as I understand, they do the same. Or is there a difference?

Comment: well, using `list(states.items())` *needlessly* creates a list of tuples and iterates over that instead of iterating over the items-view directly. Don't do that.

Comment: for iteration the same, but as object the differe

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Needless until you want to modify the dictionary during the iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well they are the same in this particular example. As you can see:

```
>>> states.items()
dict_items([('Oregon', 'OR'), ('Florida', 'FL'), ('California', 'CA'), ('New York', 'NY'), ('Michigan', 'MI')])
>>> type(_)
<class 'dict_items'>
>>>
```

The `items` function returns a `dict_items` object.

And it has a `__iter__` attribute:

```
>>> dir(states.items())
['__and__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__or__', '__rand__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__ror__', '__rsub__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__xor__', 'isdisjoint']
>>>
```

Which means it supports iteration.

But if you try anything with it:

```
>>> states.items()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    states.items()[0]
TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

It would give a `TypeError`.

The `dict_items` class is something like:

```
class dict_items:
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        ...
```

It supports iteration but nothing else.

Whereas if you convert it to a `list`:

```
>>> list(states.items())
[('Oregon', 'OR'), ('Florida', 'FL'), ('California', 'CA'), ('New York', 'NY'), ('Michigan', 'MI')]
>>>
```

It would give a regular list of tuples, that is obviously iterable as well, but it is completely not needed in this situation.

As @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, using `list(states.items())` needlessly creates a list of tuples and iterates over that instead of iterating over the items-view directly.

In some other situations, using `list` is required. If you want to convert a dictionary to a list of tuples, `list(states.items())` would be the way to go.

Comment: Because I see reasons why they're not the same (see my answer). In their particular toy demonstration that they created for this question it doesn't matter, but in other cases there *are* reasons to create that list.

Comment: @KellyBundy Of course they're different, Also in my answer i am talking about this particular situation.

Comment: @KellyBundy Edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Wasn't clear before, as the question title, question text (except the MRE), and your answer all made it sound general.

Comment: *"It supports iteration but nothing else"* - It also supports set operations.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason you might want to iterate over a list of the items is that it allows you to modify the dict during the iteration, adding new items to the dict or removing old ones.

If you iterate over the dict directly and make such modifications, the iteration will complain with an error and crash.

It won't crash if you just modify the values belonging to existing keys, but in that case, the iteration with the list gives you the old values while iterating over the dict directly gives you the current (possibly already changed during earlier items) values. Getting the old values might be what you want if you for example write a game of life simulator and need to compute the next state from the old state, without the computation of the next state affecting itself.

Doesn't need to be a list, just needs to be some copy of the items, so you're not iterating over the dict directly. Could for example use tuple, deqeue or even dict instead.

If you don't want to modify but just print like in your toy example, then creating the list is just a pointless waste of memory and time.